# Cloning from a Bitbucket server gives "git: 'http-backend' is not a git command."

Tags: ubuntu, git

When we try to clone the repo using the git tool, we get the following error. The git version we are using is 2.33.1, but there is a problem.

```
$ git clone http://local.com/bitbucket/scm/test/test1.git
Cloning into 'test1'...
Username for 'http://local.com': admin
Password for 'http://admin@local.com': 
fatal: unable to access 'http://local.com/bitbucket/scm/test/test1.git/': The requested URL returned error: 500


ERROR:

2021-11-02 14:26:26,703 ERROR [http-scmrequest-handler:thread-1] @1RWC27Hx866x126x0 192.168.4.1,127.0.0.1 "GET /scm/test/test1.git/info/refs HTTP/1.1" c.a.s.i.s.g.p.h.GitSmartExitHandler TEST/test1[3]: Read request from 192.168.4.1 failed
The following was written to stderr:
git: 'http-backend' is not a git command. See 'git --help'.
com.atlassian.utils.process.ProcessException: Non-zero exit code: 1
    at com.atlassian.bitbucket.internal.process.nu.NioNuProcessHandler.callExitHandler(NioNuProcessHandler.java:332)
    at com.atlassian.bitbucket.internal.process.nu.NioNuProcessHandler.finish(NioNuProcessHandler.java:381)
    at com.atlassian.bitbucket.internal.process.nu.NioNuProcessHandler.onExit(NioNuProcessHandler.java:136)
    at com.zaxxer.nuprocess.internal.BasePosixProcess.onExit(BasePosixProcess.java:315)
    at com.zaxxer.nuprocess.linux.ProcessEpoll.handleExit(ProcessEpoll.java:365)
    at com.zaxxer.nuprocess.linux.ProcessEpoll.cleanupProcess(ProcessEpoll.java:318)
    at com.zaxxer.nuprocess.linux.ProcessEpoll.process(ProcessEpoll.java:253)
    at com.zaxxer.nuprocess.internal.BaseEventProcessor.run(BaseEventProcessor.java:82)
    at com.zaxxer.nuprocess.linux.ProcessEpoll.run(ProcessEpoll.java:154)
    at com.zaxxer.nuprocess.linux.LinuxProcess.run(LinuxProcess.java:110)
    at com.zaxxer.nuprocess.linux.LinProcessFactory.runProcess(LinProcessFactory.java:50)
    at com.zaxxer.nuprocess.NuProcessBuilder.run(NuProcessBuilder.java:273)
    at com.atlassian.bitbucket.internal.process.nu.NuNioProcessHelper.run(NuNioProcessHelper.java:75)
    at com.atlassian.bitbucket.internal.process.NioCommand.call(NioCommand.java:46)
    at com.atlassian.stash.internal.scm.git.protocol.http.GitSmartRequest.handleRequest(GitSmartRequest.java:80)
    at com.atlassian.stash.internal.scm.git.protocol.http.HttpOtherRead.handleRequest(HttpOtherRead.java:16)
    at com.atlassian.stash.internal.scm.ThrottledScmRequestFactory$AbstractThrottledScmRequest.handleRequest(ThrottledScmRequestFactory.java:56)
    at com.atlassian.stash.internal.scm.DefaultHttpScmRequestExecutor.runSync(DefaultHttpScmRequestExecutor.java:173)
    at com.atlassian.stash.internal.scm.DefaultHttpScmRequestExecutor.access$200(DefaultHttpScmRequestExecutor.java:48)
    at com.atlassian.stash.internal.scm.DefaultHttpScmRequestExecutor$ScmAsyncRequest.run(DefaultHttpScmRequestExecutor.java:361)
    at com.atlassian.stash.internal.request.DefaultRequestManager.lambda$wrapForAsync$0(DefaultRequestManager.java:169)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
    ... 1 frame trimmed
```

Comment: so your question is? (I think to you and me its equally clear that your bitbucket server isn't correctly set up)

Comment: `sudo apt-get remove git`

`sudo apt-get remove --auto-remove git`

`sudo apt-get purge git`

`sudo apt-get purge --auto-remove git`

`apt install liberror-perl git-man=1:2.25.1-1ubuntu3.2 git=1:2.25.1-1ubuntu3.2`

The problem is that bitbucket version 7.15.1 does not support git version 2.33. I fixed the problem with the following commands. Hope it helps those who encounter this problem.

@MarcusMüller

Comment: you still haven't asked a question in your *question* post, otherwise I'd recommend you post this as an answer to said question yourself. Then it might help someone else.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that bitbucket version 7.15.1 does not support git version 2.33. I fixed the problem with the following commands. Hope it helps those who encounter this problem

```
sudo apt-get remove git 
sudo apt-get remove --auto-remove 
git sudo apt-get purge 
git sudo apt-get purge --auto-remove 
git apt install liberror-perl  git-man=1:2.25.1-1ubuntu3.2  git=1:2.25.1-1ubuntu3.2
```